# Sysout comes out before function finished

Tags: java, function, system.out

What I try to do :

```
Call function1 => set values 
Call function2 => GetValues
Sysout => print the modified values
```

My problem, the sysout comes befor I do "Set Values" so it shows me the old values.

What did I do wrong ?

Here is my code :

```
System.out.println("Cmd before SetParam : "+info1+"/"+info2+"/"+info3+"/"+info4+"/"+info5+"/"+info6+"/"+info7+"/"+info8);

TMSSA2_1.SetParam(info1,info2,info3,info4,info5,info6,info7,info8);

String[] cmd = new String[8];

cmd = TMSSA2_1.GetCmd();

System.out.println("New Cmd  => "+Arrays.toString(cmd));
```

So my output look like :

```
cMD before SetParam : 45/128/128/128/128/128/0/0

New Cmd  => [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
SetParam => ok
GetCmd => Ok
```

So you can see that my 2 functions are called after my sysout.

EDIT :

Full Functions code :

```
static int Check_jb1 = 0;
static int Check_jb2 = 0;

public static String[] Commande = new String[8];

public static void SetParam(final String info1,final String info2,final String info3,final String info4,
        final String info5,final String info6,final String info7,final String info8){

    String d1 = info1,d2 = info2,d3 = info3,d4 = info4,d5 = info5,d6 = info6,d7 = info7,d8 = info8;



    final String[] cmd = new String[8];
    cmd[0] = d1;        cmd[1] = d2;        cmd[2] = d3;        cmd[3] = d4;
    cmd[4] = d5;        cmd[5] = d6;        cmd[6] = d7;        cmd[7] = d8;


    //d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8; // valeur que l'on renvoie ds la cmd

    System.out.println("Debug : "+d1+"/"+d2+"/"+d3+"/"+d4+"/"+d5+"/"+d6+"/"+d7+"/"+d8);


    final JFrame fenetre = new JFrame();
    fenetre.setTitle("Set Value(s)");
    fenetre.setSize(375,450);
    fenetre.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    fenetre.setResizable(true);

    JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
    jp1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Set Parameters : "));
    jp1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(325, 325));
    jp1.setBackground(Color.white);

    JLabel jl1 = new JLabel();
    jl1.setText("Installation Height : "+info1);
    jl1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 25));
    final JTextField jt1 = new JTextField();
    jt1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75, 25));

    JLabel jl2 = new JLabel();
    jl2.setText("Install Offset : "+info2);
    jl2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 25));
    final JTextField jt2 = new JTextField();
    jt2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75, 25));

    JLabel jl3 = new JLabel();
    jl3.setText("Speed Near Lane : "+info3);
    jl3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 25));
    final JTextField jt3 = new JTextField();
    jt3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75, 25));

    JLabel jl4 = new JLabel();
    jl4.setText("Speed Far Lane : "+info4);
    jl4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 25));
    final JTextField jt4 = new JTextField();
    jt4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75, 25));

    JLabel jl5 = new JLabel();
    jl5.setText("Lenght Near Lane : "+info5);
    jl5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 25));
    final JTextField jt5 = new JTextField();
    jt5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75, 25));

    JLabel jl6 = new JLabel();
    jl6.setText("Lenght Far Lane : "+info6);
    jl6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 25));
    final JTextField jt6 = new JTextField();
    jt6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75, 25));

    JLabel jl7 = new JLabel();
    jl7.setText("Angle Offset : "+info7);
    jl7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 25));
    final JTextField jt7 = new JTextField();
    jt7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75, 25));

    JLabel jl8 = new JLabel();
    jl8.setText("Detector Mode : "+info8);
    jl8.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 25));
    final JTextField jt8 = new JTextField();
    jt8.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75, 25));

    JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();
    jp2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(325, 50));
    jp2.setBackground(Color.white);

    JButton jb1 = new JButton("Set with actual value");
    JButton jb2 = new JButton("Set with new value");


    fenetre.add(jp1);   
    jp1.add(jl1);jp1.add(jt1);      jp1.add(jl2);jp1.add(jt2);  jp1.add(jl3);jp1.add(jt3);  jp1.add(jl4);jp1.add(jt4);      
    jp1.add(jl5);jp1.add(jt5);      jp1.add(jl6);jp1.add(jt6);  jp1.add(jl7);jp1.add(jt7);  jp1.add(jl8);jp1.add(jt8);

    fenetre.add(jp2);
    jp2.add(jb1);
    jp2.add(jb2);


    fenetre.setVisible(true);

    jp1.setVisible(true);

    jl1.setVisible(true);   
    jl2.setVisible(true);
    jl3.setVisible(true);
    jl4.setVisible(true);
    jl5.setVisible(true);
    jl6.setVisible(true);
    jl7.setVisible(true);
    jl8.setVisible(true);

    //fenetre.getContentPane().add(JP_North, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    fenetre.getContentPane().add(jp1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    fenetre.getContentPane().add(jp2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    //while ((Check_jb2 == 0) & (Check_jb1 == 0)){

    //Garder Ancien Value
    jb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("Dans le action jb1");
            fenetre.dispose();
            Check_jb1 = 1;  
            returnCmd(cmd);
            System.out.println("JB1 : Retour => "+Arrays.toString(cmd));
        }      
    });

    //Envoyer New value
    jb2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            cmd[0] = jt1.getText();             cmd[1] = jt2.getText();             cmd[2] = jt3.getText();             cmd[3] = jt4.getText();
            cmd[4] = jt5.getText();             cmd[5] = jt6.getText();             cmd[6] = jt7.getText();             cmd[7] = jt8.getText();

            fenetre.dispose();                          
            Check_jb2 = 1;
            returnCmd(cmd);
            System.out.println("JB2 : Retour => "+ Arrays.toString(cmd));
        }      
    });
    //}
    //System.out.println("sortie du while");

}

public static String[] returnCmd (String[] Commande2){
    Commande = Commande2;
    return Commande;
}

public static String[] GetCmd(){
    return Commande;
}
```

Here is how I called them :

```
System.out.println("Cmd before SetParam : "+info1+"/"+info2+"/"+info3+"/"+info4+"/"+info5+"/"+info6+"/"+info7+"/"+info8);

TMSSA2_1.SetParam(info1,info2,info3,info4,info5,info6,info7,info8);

String[] cmd = new String[8];

cmd = TMSSA2_1.GetCmd();

System.out.println("New Cmd => "+Arrays.toString(cmd));
```

Comment: Is this your whole code? If so, why is it tagged multithreading? If not, post your whole code.

Comment: sorry, I typed Thread but dont know if it can usefull ?

Comment: Or it may happen that the other method prints to System.err in fact and then the order in which it is printed to console is not guaranteed

Comment: No I dont use Thread but maybe it could be a solution ?

Comment: Threads are not a solution. Your code does not run in the wrong order. Your code *always* runs in the exact order you tell it to, unless you're using threads (which you're not). So post the rest of your code (using the edit link underneath your question) so other people can see it and figure out the problem.

Comment: @immibis : I edited my code, can you check ?

Comment: Well, `GetCmd` returns `Commande`, and `SetParam` doesn't ever set `Commande`, at least not until you press a button, which happens after `SetParam` returns (it just creates a window, and it sets it up so something happens when the user presses a button, but it doesn't wait around for that to happen)

Comment: Actually, "SetParam" sets Commande by calling "returnCmd(cmd)". But you are right about the waiting stuff, How can I do that ? Make the sysout wait until i press the button ?

Comment: but I don't understand because my 2 actionlistener are in the "SetParam" function, so the sysout must wait until setParam ends , right ?

Comment: SetParam ends after the window is set up. Not after a button is clicked.

Comment: Yeah I got that now but is't possible to create an actionlistener on another one ? This should be the way to do it, right ? Or could you give me a beginning of a solution ?